# how should I start with python working on database?

Tags: php, python, mysql, sqlite, wamp

I am completely new to **python** and I want to start working with **database** in python and I am using **winPython version 3.4**.
 I had some experience with **php** and **mysql** which were both installed and coordinated in **wampserver**. I could make databases and write queries to it with no problem.
 But in python I don’t know how I can access the mysql or sqlite3 using cmd or any graphical interface and create database to be able to send queries to.
-Do I have to **install mysql or sqlite3 database server** first?
 -If I need to **install specific python libraries**, how can I get a **visual interface** like **phpmyadmin in wamp** or **cmd** in windows?
If you could show me a way which I could use the **phpmyadmin** in **wampserver** **in coordination with python** just like **php**, that would be the best solution to me.( because it seems version 3.4 doesn’t match with mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you could install XAMPP or WAMP if under Windows operating system, so you'd have apache server, mysql, ftp, tomcat, and you'd be able to use phpmyadmin to edit your database, or you could just use mysql server if you know how to set it up. Then just install [mysqlclent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient)  mysql driver, and here is the user [guide](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst.) for it. You need username and password to connect to database and you do it almost the same as in php, just in a python syntax.
Read the guide and you should get how to connect and query your database.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 database has no server. you can nevertheles use it with a gui:

- launch "WinPython Command Prompt.exe"
- type "sqlite_bro"